# Matlab: multiple images not properly aligned with 'axis equal'

Tags: matlab, axis, figure

How can I remove the white space between the sub-images in the following code?

```
    fig = figure ;
set(fig, 'units', 'centimeter', 'position', [1 1 20 10])

a(1) = subplot(1,2,1) ;
imagesc(rand(4)), colormap gray

a(2) = subplot(2,2,2) ;
imagesc(rand(2,4))

a(3) = subplot(2,4,7) ;
imagesc(rand (2,2))

a(4) = subplot(2,4,8) ;
imagesc(rand (2,2))

axis(a, 'equal', 'tight')
set(a, 'xticklabel', [], 'yticklabel', [])
```

---

Save and Play this function to see where the plots actually are, and where Matlab think they are.

```
function showAxesBoundaries(fig)

if nargin==0
fig = figure ;
set(fig, 'units', 'centimeter', 'position', [1 1 30 10])

a(1) = subplot(1,2,1) ;
imagesc(rand(4)), colormap gray

a(2) = subplot(2,2,2) ;
imagesc(rand(2,4))

a(3) = subplot(2,4,7) ;
imagesc(rand (2,2))

a(4) = subplot(2,4,8) ;
imagesc(rand (2,2))

axis(a, 'equal', 'tight')

end

h = findobj(fig, 'tag', 'axesboundary');
if ~isempty(h)
delete(h);
end

handles.axes = findobj(fig, 'type', 'axes', '-not', 'tag', 'globalaxes');

if isempty(handles.axes)
error('TODO');
end

ax = axes('units', 'normalized', 'position', [0 0 1 1], ...
'visible', 'off', 'tag', 'globalaxes');

for n = 1:numel(handles.axes)

outerposition = get(handles.axes(n), 'outerposition');
position = get(handles.axes(n), 'position');
tightinset = get(handles.axes(n), 'tightinset');

axes(ax);

handles.r(1,n) = rectangle('position', outerposition, 'linestyle', '--', ...
'edgecolor', 'y', 'tag', 'axesboundary', 'linewidth', 2);
handles.r(2,n) = rectangle('position', position, 'linestyle', '--', ...
'edgecolor', 'g', 'tag', 'axesboundary', 'linewidth', 2);
handles.r(3,n) = rectangle('position', position+[-1 -1 1 1].*tightinset+[0 0 tightinset(1:2)], 'linestyle', '--', ...
'edgecolor', 'r', 'tag', 'axesboundary', 'linewidth', 2);
end

set(fig, 'resizefcn', {@rzfcn handles});

function rzfcn(hObject, event, handles)

for n = 1:numel(handles.axes)

outerposition = get(handles.axes(n), 'outerposition');
position = get(handles.axes(n), 'position');
tightinset = get(handles.axes(n), 'tightinset');

set(handles.r(1,n), 'position', outerposition);
set(handles.r(2,n), 'position', position);
set(handles.r(3,n), 'position', position+[-1 -1 1 1].*tightinset+[0 0 tightinset(1:2)]);
end

drawnow
refresh
```

Comment: This code actually errors out in Octave when trying to run the `axis` command: "error: axis: limits(1) must be less than limits(2)".

Comment: This is a code for Matlab, not Octave. (see keywords). I have edited the title for more clarity

Comment: Yes, I understood, but I was just pointing out that the reason why it doesn't quite work in MATLAB may be the same reason why it errors out in Octave. For simple commands such as `plot`, `axis`, etc... they are fairly equivalent and interchangeable.

Comment: Did you check out the result from applying `axis equal` after each plot step? I would say Matlab's behavior is valid in both cases.

Comment: I think it works fine. When you mean "missaligned" you mean that image 1 doesnt start in the same screen position than other images, rigth? However I think thats intentional. If you dont force the plots to be an specific shape, Matlab makes them so they are the same "screen size", but if you force sizes dont expect them to be the same "screen size"! There are several cases where that effect is imposible if you use axis equal axis tight! (actually in general)

Comment: no, it is not quite normal. if you play the code below (just run the function with no argument), you can see that the images are not where Matlab think they are!

Comment: If you want to delete ALL the white  space between you graphs, why not just plot 1?

Comment: because I have 4 different maps at four different scales to plot in one single figure.

Comment: And are theyr sizes "attachable", as in the exmaple, or its just a coincidence? Note that you can create a 4x8 matrix pasting your data.

Comment: Because we go to the same problem: If they are attachable, well, attach them and plot them in just 1 plot! you can add some darker lines to visualy diferenciate or wathever. If they are not, then you have the problem I stated in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think it makes sense. Your problem is the next one, rigth?

[image]

**In short**: Axis equal, axis tight makes the figure engine to missaling the subplots, and that's it.

But how do you expect to solve it?

To fit the big figure to the rest it would need to be increased in both x and Y. you can try to increase by hand the size of the window and you would see how the first subplots gets bigger. You can make it same size and avoid that misalignment. But what about the second (long) subfigure? If you increase the size of the figure horizontally all the rest are forced to grow also!

you can imagine a lot of different sceneries with different size of subplots and data where an alignment of all subplots is impossible with `axis equal axis tight`. So logically Matlab decided (i guess) not to try.

Another impossible case that is easier to see:

```
fig = figure(1);
set(fig, 'units', 'centimeter', 'position', [1 1 20 10])

a(1) = subplot(2,4,[1 2 5 6]) ;
imagesc(rand(100)), colormap gray
axis equal
axis tight
a(2) = subplot(2,4,3:4) ;
imagesc(rand(2,400))
axis equal;axis tight
a(3) = subplot(2,4,7) ;
imagesc(rand (2,2))
axis equal;axis tight
a(4) = subplot(2,4,8) ;
imagesc(rand (2,25))
axis equal;axis tight
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change each axis' `'Position'` property. For example,

```
set(a(1), 'Position', get(a(1),'Position') + [-.03 -.03 .06 .06])
set(a(2), 'Position', get(a(2),'Position') + [-.03 -.03 .06 .06])
set(a(3), 'Position', get(a(3),'Position') + [-.03 -.03 .06 .06])
set(a(4), 'Position', get(a(4),'Position') + [-.03 -.03 .06 .06])
```

You'll have to manually change those numbers to get good results.

Comment: thanks. I will do this way. less than perfect, but I beleive there is no better way.